# Symfony Doctrine Count ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an `User` entity with a many-to-many entity (`Wish`) linked to it, I now need the top 10 wishes now using the Symfony QueryBuilder.

The problem here is that i do not have direct access to the ManyToMany Table/Entity/Repository as its automatically created and managed by Doctrine ORM.

Making a manual OneToMany, ManyToOne Entity is not really an option as it will break existing code (mostly the automatic collection population and the add / remove functions of it)

Doing a manual SQL is kinda dodgy since the table name is generated and might change some update (even if not I would prefer to keep it clean)

some code:

```
class User {
// .........
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Wish")
 */
private $wish;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->wish = new ArrayCollection(); // with get/set/add/remove etc
}
}


class Wish {
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;
// ... get set etc
}
```

Comment: you have to declare your relation to doctrine for it to handle it. You can surely in this case, create a custom Repository and create a query DQL to limit your results to 10.

Comment: @hoover_D how would i do that? the relevant data is in the relation table 'user_wish' and i have no entity nor repository of it

Comment: check here documentation for mapping relations https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html, when you do the settings It will be easier to do your custom Repository, here the docs for it https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/doctrine/repository.html

Comment: @hoover_D unless im missing something this doesn't address my issue. i already have all of that but since its an automatic many to many relationship its like the join table does not exist. have any (pseudo) code that can clear things up?

Comment: Naa, you see it from the wrong side. You dont need to work directly with the join table, Doctrine does it for you. 
So you could write a special getter in the User Entity for it. Copy the Getter for Wishes inside your User Entity and rename it to something like "getWishesTopTen". Then you rewrite this getter so it doesn't give you all the Wishes, but apply Criteria to give you only the Top 10. For Criteria see this Tutorial (in the Example it's a OneToMany-Relation but it works with ManyToMany as well):
https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/collections/criteria-collection-filtering

Comment: @BenjaminKozlowski the thing is that its not about the user. its about the global top 10. i have no user so thats why im struggling, because im missing an entry point to get the data

Comment: Ah, ok. So how is "Top 10" defined?

Comment: @BenjaminKozlowski its defined by using something like `SELECT wish_id, count(wish_id) AS c FROM user_wish GROUP BY wish_id` in a sql statement on the join table

Comment: So, you want the wishes that have the most users. So first you'd have to add the Users to your Wish Entity. Then you could count them. Take a look here: 
https://gist.github.com/Ocramius/3121916
Then you could write a query for Wishes that counts the Users that are associated with it.

Comment: i see. i was against exposing the users in the wish but this is a good argument and could work, will try tomorrow

Comment: @BenjaminKozlowski yea its not working. whatever i do i can't get the query builder to accept selecting the users. i will use a static sql query for now